# Изменение данных в DataFrame с помощью функции

Tags: python, dataframe

Есть DataFrame:

```py
states = ['California', 'Florida', 'Massachusetts', 'Minnesota']

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        year=np.random.choice((2014, 2015, 2016), 100),
        cntry=['United States' for _ in range(100)],
        State=np.random.choice(states, 100),
        Col1=np.random.randint(0, 20, 100),
        Col2=np.random.randint(0, 20, 100),
        Col3=np.random.randint(0, 20, 100),
        ))

df.head()

    year       cntry            State     Col1  Col2 Col3
0   2016    United States   California      8   6   15
1   2014    United States   Minnesota       5   3   0
2   2015    United States   Florida         10  0   3
3   2014    United States   Florida         14  16  15
4   2016    United States   Massachusetts   0   7   14
```

Хочу обработать его с помощью функции:

```
def defined_value(df, col1, col2, col3):
    for row in df.itertuples():
        result = row.col1 + row.col2 + row.col3
        if result > 10:
            return str('Result > 10: ', result)

df.loc[:, 'test_1'] = defined_value(df, 'Col1', 'Col2', 'Col2')
```

Получаю следующую ошибку:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-a0908c223773> in <module>()
----> 1 df.loc[:, 'test_1'] = defined_value(df, 'Col1', 'Col2', 'Col2')

<ipython-input-26-6194bd333695> in defined_value(df, col1, col2, col3)
      2     for row in df.itertuples():
      3         col1 = 'Col1'
----> 4         result = row.col1 + row.col2 + row.col3
      5         if result > 10:
      6             return str('Result > 10: ', result)

AttributeError: 'Pandas' object has no attribute 'col1'
```

Проблема состоит в том, что я не могу передать параметрически имена колонок в функцию. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно сделать для функции `itertuples()`?
Вызов `defined_value(df, Col1, Col2, Col3)` так же вызывает ошибку.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-f136375764ac> in <module>()
----> 1 df.loc[:, 'test_1'] = defined_value(df, Col1, Col2, Col3)

NameError: name 'Col1' is not defined
```

Comment: Лайк за то, что пример воспроизводимый

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы неверно подходите к решению задачи и нарушаете идеалогию pandas. При работе с таблицами pandas стоит придерживаться функционального подхода.

## Работа с pandas

*Проще всего понять функциональный подход так*. У вас есть функция, которая на вход принимает аргументы и на выходе отдаёт результат. Важно, что данная функция не хранит состояние. Иными словами, если вы её вызовите с аргументом, `x`, а потом ещё раз вызовите с аргументом `x`, то результаты совпадут. Это означает, что функция ничего не запоминает внутри себя.

Здесь можно провести метафору: представьте, что у вас есть труба, в которую вливается вода и выливается нагретая вода. В данном случае труба это последовательность действий, которые происходят с водой. Действия -- это нагревание воды. Вход -- холодная вода. Выход -- нагретая вода.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В ряде случаев этим можно принебрегать. Но следует понимать, что скорее всего Вы поплатитесь за это производительностью по памяти и скорости.

## Обсуждение

Для перебора не стоит использовать функции `iterrows()` и `itertuples()`. По опыту, они работают медленнее, чем `apply()`. В большинстве случаев, `apply()` достаточно. Но, очевидно, с помощью `iterrows()` можно сделать больше.

#### Поговорим про отличия `iterrows()` и `itertuples()`.

#### iterrows()

Главное отличие состоит в том, что `iterrows()` возвращает массив, которая состоит из двух элементов: `[index in DataFrame, row]`

Пример:

```
list(df.iterrows())[0]
```

Вывод:

```
(0, year              2016
 cntry    United States
 State    Massachusetts
 Col1                10
 Col2                 8
 Col3                 0
 Name: 0, dtype: object)
```

Чтобы обратиться к конкретному полю, Вам нужно:

```
list(df.iterrows())[0][1]['cntry']
```

Вывод:

```
'United States'
```

#### `itertuples()`:

```
list(df.itertuples())[0]
```

Вывод:

```
Pandas(Index=0, year=2016, cntry='United States', State='Massachusetts', Col1=10, Col2=8, Col3=0)
```

Как видим, этот тип похож на `namedtuple` из `collection.namedtuple`. Я не знаю, как устроена внутренняя кухня в pandas в данном случае и что из себя представляет `collection.namedtuple` под капотом, но выскажу предположение, что

```
type(list(df.itertuples())[0])  # pandas.core.frame.Pandas
```

-- это наследник `collection.namedtuple`. Тогда к его полям нужно обращаться так:

```
list(df.itertuples())[0].year
```

Вывод:

```
2016
```

#### Теперь вернёмся к Вашей функции

```
def defined_value(df, col1, col2, col3):
    for row in df.itertuples():
        result = row.col1 + row.col2 + row.col3
        if result > 10:
            return str('Result > 10: ', result)
```

Вы её вызываете вот так:

```
df.loc[:, 'test_1'] = defined_value(df, 'Col1', 'Col2', 'Col2')
```

Упростим:

```
defined_value(df, 'Col1', 'Col2', 'Col2')
```

Функция сломается тут:

```
result = row.col1 + row.col2 + row.col3
```

Если рашифровать эту строку, то получится странная конструкция:

```
result = row.'Сol1' + row.'Col2' + row.'Col3'
```

Я не уверен, но скорее всего такая конструкция в python3.7 и ранее не валидна в принципе. Для того, чтобы решить эту проблему, можно поступить так:

```
for row in df.iterrows():
    result = row[1][col1] + row[1][col2] + row[1][col3]
```

Мы заменили `itertuples()` на `iterrows()` и стали обращаться к колонкам через оператор `[]`. Если хочется использовать `itertuples()`, то скорее всего Вам придётся сильно переделать код. Я этот случай рассматривать не буду.

Есть также нюанс с выводом строки. Нужно делать так:

```
return 'Result > 10: %f' % result
```

Далее у Вас возникнет проблема с ответом от функции:

```
def defined_value(df, col1, col2, col3):
    for row in df.iterrows():
        result = row[1][col1] + row[1][col2] + row[1][col3]
        if result > 10:
            return 'Result > 10: %f' % result
```

Она вернёт Вам одну единственную строку:

```
'Result > 10: 26.000000'
```

Если мы попробуем выполнить Ваш вызов целиком, то наткнёмся на проблему: размер `pd.DataFrame` отличается от количества возвращаемых значений. Размер равен 5 (число строк), а возвращаемое значение -- 1:

```
df.loc[:, 'test_1'] = defined_value(df, 'Col1', 'Col2', 'Col2')
df['test_1']
```

Тогда запись произведётся во все строки:

```
0     Result > 10: 26.000000
1     Result > 10: 26.000000
2     Result > 10: 26.000000
3     Result > 10: 26.000000
...
96    Result > 10: 26.000000
97    Result > 10: 26.000000
98    Result > 10: 26.000000
99    Result > 10: 26.000000
Name: test_1, Length: 100, dtype: object
```

Мне кажется, что подразумевалась не эта операция. Для того, чтобы это поправить, Вам нужно возвращать либо массив объектов:

```
def defined_value(df, col1, col2, col3):
    res = []
    for row in df.iterrows():
        result = row[1][col1] + row[1][col2] + row[1][col3]
        if result > 10:
            res.append('Result > 10: %f' % result)
        else:
            res.append('Result <= 10: %f' % result)
    return res

df.loc['test_1'] = defined_value(df, 'Col1', 'Col2', 'Col2')
```

, либо создать генератор и преобразовать его к списку. Я не люблю, когда функции возвращают большие наборы данных, поэтому призываю использовать генератор. В таком случае, в общем случае, Вы не порождаете большое количество данных, которые могут порвать память. В данном случае, это ничего не решает. Второй момент. Я не люблю `else`, поскольку это хуже читается для меня. В таком случае, не всегда сразу ясно и очевидно, что является else. Кроме того, это лишняя строка, которая засоряет пространство. Взамен этого, я пользуюсь операторами `continue`, `break`, `return` (это -- вкусовщина):

```
def defined_value(df, col1, col2, col3):
    res = []
    for row in df.iterrows():
        result = row[1][col1] + row[1][col2] + row[1][col3]
        if result > 10:
            yield 'Result > 10: %f' % result
            continue
        # Иногда я явно пишу второе условие: if result <= 10:
        yield 'Result <= 10: %f' % result
    return

df.loc['test_1'] = list(defined_value(df, 'Col1', 'Col2', 'Col2'))
```

Если Вы никогда не пользовались генераторами, то знайте, что при вызове функции:

```
defined_value(df, 'Col1', 'Col2', 'Col2')
```

будет создан объект генератора. А далее, при вызове `list()` будет произведено итерирование по всем объектам.

Что касается финального решения, то я бы воспользовался методом `apply()`. Попробуйте изучить, как его применять и реализовать соответствующее решение.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за широкий обзор и объяснение.!!! Мне как раз очень интересно погрузиться в данную тему!

Answer (score 1):

При работе с Pandas, желательно всегда сначала попытаться найти векторизированное решение (без использования циклов, `.apply()`, etc.).

Векторизированное решение с использованием функции [pd.cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```
def vect_func(df):
    x = df[["Col1","Col2","Col3"]].sum(axis=1)
    bins = [-np.inf, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, np.inf]
    labels = [f"(result < {i} , " for i in range(10, 60, 10)] + ["result >= 50"]
    return pd.cut(x, bins=bins, labels=labels, right=False).astype(str) + x.astype(str) + ")"


df["new"] = df.pipe(vect_func)
```

---

результат:

```
In [42]: df
Out[42]:
    year          cntry          State  Col1  Col2  Col3                price                 new
0   2016  United States        Florida    14     5    16  (result < 40: , 35)  (result < 40 , 35)
1   2014  United States     California     7    15     2  (result < 30: , 24)  (result < 30 , 24)
2   2015  United States        Florida    17    14    16  (result < 50: , 47)  (result < 50 , 47)
3   2015  United States        Florida     1     7     7  (result < 20: , 15)  (result < 20 , 15)
4   2016  United States     California    11    19    13  (result < 50: , 43)  (result < 50 , 43)
5   2015  United States        Florida     5    15    11  (result < 40: , 31)  (result < 40 , 31)
6   2015  United States        Florida    17     6     2  (result < 30: , 25)  (result < 30 , 25)
..   ...            ...            ...   ...   ...   ...                  ...                 ...
93  2014  United States      Minnesota     2     8    18  (result < 30: , 28)  (result < 30 , 28)
94  2014  United States        Florida     4    15     2  (result < 30: , 21)  (result < 30 , 21)
95  2016  United States  Massachusetts     3    16     6  (result < 30: , 25)  (result < 30 , 25)
96  2014  United States  Massachusetts     7    15    11  (result < 40: , 33)  (result < 40 , 33)
97  2016  United States     California    16     3    18  (result < 40: , 37)  (result < 40 , 37)
98  2016  United States     California     0     5    13  (result < 20: , 18)  (result < 20 , 18)
99  2014  United States        Florida     4     6     9  (result < 20: , 19)  (result < 20 , 19)

[100 rows x 8 columns]
```

---

замеры времени:

```
In [43]: %timeit df.apply(lambda row: valuation_formula(row['Col1'], row['Col2'], row['Col3']), axis=1)
5.94 ms ± 49.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [44]: %timeit df.pipe(vect_func)
4.69 ms ± 5.31 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

для DataFrame со 100.000 строк, разница во времени будет очень заметной:

```
In [45]: df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)

In [46]: df.shape
Out[46]: (100000, 8)

In [47]: %timeit df.apply(lambda row: valuation_formula(row['Col1'], row['Col2'], row['Col3']), axis=1)
4.57 s ± 5.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [48]: %timeit df.pipe(vect_func)
208 ms ± 2.37 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Спасибо!!! Есть о чем подумать...

Comment: @MaxUспасибо за pd.cut() - красивая и очень полезная функция!!!

Comment: @БорисЖуравлев, всегда пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 0):

Принципиально вопрос решил так:

```
def valuation_formula(x, y, z):
    result = (x + y + z)
    if 10 > result:
        string = 'result < 10: '
        return string, result
    elif 10 <= result < 20:
        string = 'result < 20: '
        return string, result
    elif 20 <= result < 30:
        string = 'result < 30: '
        return string, result
    elif 30 <= result < 40:
        string = 'result < 40: '
        return string, result
    elif 40 <= result < 50:
        string = 'result < 50: '
        return string, result
    elif result >= 50:
        string = 'result > 50: '
        return string, result
    else:
        print(x, y, z, result)


df['price'] = df.apply(lambda row: valuation_formula(row['Col1'], row['Col2'], row['Col3']), axis=1)
df.head()
```

Но хотел бы увидеть решение с помощью функции itertuples().